# Is graduating early from college or transferring to another college fine if I took all the upper level courses?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, transfer-student

I'm currently a sophomore at a small liberal arts college. I want to get into one of physics PhD programs with faculties renowned for quantum gravity. I'm majoring in math and physics, and since both departments in my college are small, I will have taken all the upper-level courses in math and physics until the next semester. My major GPA in physics is 4.0, and my GRE physics score is 990, but I will have no math or physics course to take after the next semester. There aren't much research opportunities here. The only research opportunity is available during summer (which is experimental physics, but I'm mainly interested in hep-th). All REUs are not available for international students. (However, there are a few programs available for int'l students, such as Caltech SURF.)

Which of the following choices would be the best?

- Graduating early (3 yrs), going to physics PhD program, and saving $>60k. If I don't get into programs of my choice, I will either stay in the college, in the program until the end, or (hopefully) transferring to them after getting non-terminal Master's degree if I will have a compelling reason.
- Transferring to a high ranked research university for advanced/grad-level physics courses and for more research opportunities
- Staying for 4 yrs in the current institution

Comment: If you've got the credits to graduate, I can't think of any reason not to try and go straight for the PhD program.  I'm a grad student myself though - I'll defer to whatever the real PhDs have to say.

Comment: Why do you have to decide now? Apply to strong PhD programs **and** apply to transfer to strong research universities, and then see what opportunities are actually available.

Comment: OK. I will try that to see what will be available!

Comment: Why have you taken the physics GRE as a sophomore?

Comment: @JeffE the asker is considering transferring in 2016.  If the transfer happens, Aran would go to graduate school in 2018.  Otherwise, Aran would go to graduate school in 2017.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki I chose the second option and it worked well for me.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I took it as a freshman, since I thought I was prepared for it. Your interpretation of my situation is totally accurate. I'm relieved to hear that transferring can be successful in this sort of situation!

Comment: *Transferring* is a terrible idea as you will have to retake a lot of coursework. Universities are very rigid creatures. Apply for PhD and maybe some undergrad institutions for a second bachelors. **Do not transfer.** The fact that you got a 990 on the Physics GRE is huge and I think you'd stand a good chance of getting in. Some physics departments have entrance exams to see what stream of PhD courses you should do. These schools might work best for you.

Comment: @CameronWilliams false.  Some universities will require repeat coursework, others will not.  Get it in writing before you transfer.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I don't think a university could maintain accreditation if it didn't require its students to take their version of the core courses, reviewed during the accreditation process.  That's not to say that repeat coursework would be required, one could certainly take advanced courses from a more well-known school and graduate based on the requirements fulfilled earlier, but the degree would come from the first university, where the required classes were taken, and it would be the advanced course credits that would be transferred.

Comment: Another option, partway between transferring and going to grad school, is to go to Cambridge and do Part III.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I've never once heard of a university accepting more than maybe two years worth of credit hours for a transfer student. I would say a very large portion would not be receptive to it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the question specifies less than two years of credit.

Comment: @BenVoigt transfer of core courses is permitted at nearly all American universities.  In some cases, it is mandated by the government.  Also, a few universities have no core requirements, such as Brown.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I think you're talking about university-wide requirements, sometimes called "general education" or the like.  I'm talking about courses which are central to a particular degree program, neither basic prerequisites, nor advanced electives.  It is not possible for a serious university to have no core course requirements, ABET will not accredit engineering degree programs that do not meet certain minimums for core topics, and I suspect that other fields have similar accreditation requirements.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Somehow I missed that! In that case, I think transferring is the way to go.

Comment: @BenVoigt  core means general education.  I am not familiar with ABET, but what is the value of accreditation if courses from accredited institutions cannot transfer?  Transfer of credits can be governed by agreements between institutions, or it can be decided on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I assure you, when I said "I don't think a university could maintain accreditation if it didn't require its students to take their version of the core courses, reviewed during the accreditation process." I did not mean *general education* courses, which are indeed much easier to transfer.  And the value of accreditation is that the degrees are known to be meaningful, because they demonstrate a certain quality of the graduate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only in exceptional situations should an undergraduate consider "getting out early" from their undergraduate education to pursue graduate study.  Your situation is rather exceptional and is one of the better cases for doing this that I have seen.

My honest assessment is that you sound like an outstanding student who didn't make the best choice of undergraduate institution.  Liberal arts colleges can be great for a wide range of clientele, but someone who maxed out the subject exam in their intended field of graduate study in their freshman year is probably not in that range.  If you know you want to go to graduate school in physics, you want to be taking physics courses over the next three years: independent study is okay, but it is probably not good enough.

I recommend that you apply *both* to PhD programs in physics and to undergraduate programs at top tier research universities.  For the latter, you are looking for more than just being able to transfer in: you want substantial scholarship opportunities (I would aim for a "full ride") and specific access to faculty and their research.

It is of course likely that you will get admitted to better undergraduate programs than PhD programs.  In my opinion if you get into an absolutely top undergraduate program with a substantial scholarship, then that's the way to go. Most of the students who are at the very top PhD programs started out their undergraduate career with a roughly similar trajectory to yours and then built on that substantially through four years of a superb undergraduate program.  I  would be a bit surprised if you got admitted to one of the top ten programs without an undergraduate degree.

If I may throw out one specific option: the college at the University of Chicago is a lovely opportunity to get a liberal arts education in the midst of an absolutely world class research university.  You can read Plato and Kant and Dostoevsky while taking graduate courses to your heart's content.  Moreover they have full ride scholarships available for exceptional students.  (I went to the University of Chicago on a full ride scholarship, read all of the above authors, took many graduate courses in my subject of interest -- mathematics -- and then got into all the graduate programs to which I applied, including the top three.  I am more satisfied with my education at the UofC and my decision to go there than almost anything else in my life.  Seriously.)

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, applying to physics PhD without bachelor's degree is still possible now for some cases. I'm quite surprised to know that. I hope I will get some scholarship, and the amount of scholarship I will get will affect my decision greatly. Thanks for your recommendation, by the way.

Comment: @Aran: Yes, it's *possible*.  I won't make a stronger claim than that...

Comment: Disagree.  Completing your education early is fine as long as you do a good job of it.  Possibly superior since you can achieve more with the time gained.  Also, UChicago has excellent research but often poor teaching - including the mathematics department.  They are fairly transfer-friendly, though.

Comment: @Anonymous: I'm not sure I understand what you're disagreeing with.  I advised the OP to apply for PhD programs now.  About UofC:  that's a personal recommendation, not an objective claim.  For me personally, the education I received there was just shy of optimal, and I had many wonderful teachers.  If you want to share your own personal experience, please feel free.  I think though that it is more objective to say that UofC does better at placing students in quality graduate programs than almost any other undergraduate institution.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark True.

Comment: +1 for the UChicago shoutout. If there's one thing defining element of UChicago, I think it's how connected the undergrad and graduate programs are. The biggest thing I've noticed about how my undergrad experience was different from others that I've met is how much interaction I had with graduate students there, both from taking classes with them and the myriad of research opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, which may not apply in this case, is that SLACs that are in major metro areas may have agreements with nearby universities which will allow their undergraduates to take graduate classes there.  For example, Swarthmore and Penn have such an agreement.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't apply to my situation, since my school is located in middle of nowhere. The school doesn't have such agreement with the nearest university, and it takes one hour to get to the university by car, which I don't own. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring right after your sophomore year would be just fine.  People who start out in a community college do it *all the time*.  Large four-year institutions have the transfer process figured out.

I agree with others that if you transfer, you should try to get as much financial support as possible from the new institution (but without sacrificing quality).

One other factor that hasn't been mentioned is your general maturity level.  Just because you feel frustrated with the skimpy offerings at your school, doesn't necessarily mean you're ready to jump into a swimming pool full of people 2+ years older than you.  (I'm not saying you're not ready -- I don't know you; I'm only saying, please consider this aspect as well.)

I hope the above considerations help you with what is ultimately a very personal decision.

Comment: Yes. I will try my best to reduce the total cost of attendance to $30k, so that if I will transfer and stay at a new school for two years, it will not cost more than $60k. Regarding my maturity level, my adviser can decide whether I will be ready or not, so my decision is going to rely on his opinion. I appreciate your help.

Comment: With the academic successes you have achieved, you are in a good position to apply for merit scholarships.

Answer (score -1):

In support of your third option, staying at your LAC for four years:

There are plenty of interesting things to study at a liberal arts college that you might not have the time or opportunity to study once you’re in graduate school. Some of them might enrich your life and career as a physicist, like philosophy or computer science or chemistry or writing, and some of them might be fascinating and fulfilling on their own, like art history or a new foreign language.

You should also be able to study more mathematics and physics without transferring or graduating early. I’m sure your LAC offers independent study or special project courses for students who’ve exhausted the catalog curriculum. Ask your academic advisor or one of your favorite professors about that possibility.

Comment: While I am strongly in favor of a liberal arts education (in particular, I treasure mine), I am not in favor of it to the extent of spending an extra $60K for it.   As the parable goes, being a big fish in a small pond confers certain advantages, but I don't recall anything about the small pond being very, very expensive.  Sounds less fun.

Comment: Major universities have these opportunities in spades.  Your advisor might not be a fan of spending time on them, but if one is going to spend the equivalent of a couple years on breadth, much better to do it at the better school, and spread out over the entire graduate experience than making zero progress on the major subject in between meeting BS requirements and beginning graduate school.

Comment: Pete: Good point. At the best LACs, all financial aid may be need-based, but it might be worth asking about merit aid for an advanced student who would otherwise graduate early. Ben: R1 universities have many offerings, but IMHO, they can’t compete in many ways with LACs at the introductory level. (Large classes, TAs, nonmajors not able to get into classes...) This might vary widely, but when I was a grad student at an R1, had I wanted to study a new subject, for example, it would have likely been in a large class taught by a TA or instructor not committed to undergraduate education.